# Excel VBA Copy Data Validation Source to Cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a project to create a standard checklist for the services we offer. Currently, we have multiple checklists for various project types. I am currently recording the values of each list to help me better gauge how to standardize and I am building a macro to collect these values.

Some cells have Data Validation Lists. I would like to copy the Source for the list to a new cells. So instead of just copying "YES" or "NO", I would see "YES, NO".

**UPDATED**

```
Sub OptionPop1()

Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, lr As Long, x As Long, i As Long

Set wb = ThisWorkbook

With wb

    For i = 1 To wb.Worksheets.Count

        Set ws = wb.Worksheets(i)

        lr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        On Error Resume Next

        For x = 2 To lr

            ws.Cells(x, 4).Value = ws.Cells(x, 6).Validation.Formula1

        Next x

    Next i

End With

End Sub
```

Any thoughts? I haven't been able to locate similar questions.

Comment: You can get the source of a validated cell using 

`ActiveCell.Validation.Formula1` but if there is no validation in the cell, it will throw error 1004. Try to handle it with this.

Comment: That's exactly what I was missing. I've updated my code.